# Ubuntu - Destroyed my data on longside installation - Data recovery?

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I wanted to get Ubuntu 13.10 so I downloaded it.... 
Firstly I tried to install it alongside my Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit, using Wubi. It didn't worked: 
No root filesystem error on ubuntu boot

So I used my flash drive to boot ubuntu and start alongside installation on 20GB partition on my SSD just for that....
But after all, my Windows 7 and all my data was LOST.
Ubutnu was transfered my SSD drive from MBR to  EFI GPT and formated it as ext4.
I lost minecraft server world saves, thousands lines of my PHP and Python scripts, few gamesaves, a lot of text files witth important infos....
 About 1GB of data...
I still can't understand, why the fu*k Ubuntu is had to touch disk MBR?!
Now I trying to recover my data, and I do not known how, because I got much raw and damaged data........
Is there any good program for that except few ones I tried: Minitool, Easeus, GetDataBack, iCare, Recuva?
Every of these programs returns me RAW data, and just most recent .ext types for example .rar .zip .jpg .gif .png ?
I need to recover .PHP .CSS .DAT .SAV .C .BIN .MB2 .MCA .SPM .PL .PY
How I can get that done?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The Wubi installer ony works with Ubuntu 12.04 and below.

Comment: But you have backups?

Comment: @Aaron I known that, it installed me 12.04 LTS version, but it didn't worked.

Comment: @Braiam I don't have any backups. That's a brand new SSD drive, old 2 months, and worked perfectly, so I didn't maked most recent backup. Last backup I made is one month ago, but it doesn't contains much new files, etc.
I saw duplicate question, but answer didn't helped me at all.... I tried TestDisk....